# Creating a generic base entity which can be extended for each client

Tags: hibernate, ejb-3.0, eclipselink

I'm using Eclipselink and I'm trying figure out the best way to create a base class for my entity.

For example, I have a User entity and I would like to provide an extended User class for some clients, but I would like to not have to rewrite my generic queries.

So I would have a User entity and a ClientSpecificUser entity, but be able to pull up ClientSpecificUser by using the query "select e from User e".

Has anyone done something like?  What worked best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 5 Generics could be a good fit for this issue, to institute a generic DAO layer.  Here are 2 examples:

- http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects
- http://nileshk.com/2006/05/09/hibernate-dao-using-java-generics.html